# How to save string as html file in cache directory and retrieve that file from cache directory and show it in web view in android studio?

Tags: android, html, kotlin, file, webview

How to save string as html file and retrieve it and load it in webview?

I am in the situation that while hitting the api I get the response as String which is in Html format Like this as String

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> <!-- title bar --> </title>
        <!-- header for the website -->
    </head>
    <body>
       
        <!-- body section of the website -->
   
    </body>
</html>
```

I save this string as html file inside the cache directory like this

```
   val htmlFile = File(
       mContext.cacheDir,
       System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + ".html"
   )
   val out = FileOutputStream(htmlFile)
   val data: ByteArray = htmlString.toByteArray()
   out.write(data)
   out.close()
```

And retrieve that file path from `htmlFile.absolutePath` and load that path in web view.

This shows the error that Webpage is not available.

How to get the path of the html file and load it in webview?

**Note:**
when I save the html text as html file inside the assets folder and load that file as string `"file:///android_asset/test.html"` works inside the webview.

Full Code is Added Below:

```
          /*htmlString is the string obtain from api response is in html format like 
            * <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title> <!-- title bar --> </title>
                        <!-- header for the website -->
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <!-- body section of the website -->
                    </body>
                </html>
            */
            val htmlFile = File(
                mContext.cacheDir,
                System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + ".html"
            )
            val out = FileOutputStream(htmlFile)
            val data: ByteArray = htmlString.toByteArray()
            out.write(data)
            out.close()
            val htmlFilePath = htmlFile.absolutePath // Loading this in WebView Shows Error Webpage is not available
            requireActivity().apply {
                val intent= Intent(this, WebviewActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("title", "Dummy Title")
                intent.putExtra("url", htmlFilePath)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
```

Please provide the solution for my question, Thanks

Comment: `and load that path in web view.` Well where is the code? And.. you have the path already.

Comment: Yes, when i load that path it show Webpage is not available error.

Comment: Please check my code attached above

Answer (score 1):

Finally got solution for this problem

```
webview.apply {
   settings.allowContentAccess = true
   settings.allowFileAccess = true
}
```

After adding this line in webview, html file from cache dir load successfully.

Problem not in the Saving File in cache directory or retrieve it. Its about missing these two lines in webview